# How to make a thind link throw a button in a third screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

two created screens that has two button, each button links to the other, so two screens with two buttons, I don't know how to add a link to the third screen, eclipse was running it but no use

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I&apos;m screen 1 (main.xml)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me to another screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main2.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="(main2.xml) how do get to the 3rd" />
</LinearLayout>
```

AppActivity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

App2Activity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Make sure you have registered the `App3Activity` in `AndroidManifest`.

**EDIT**

Here is the complete solution, just copy paste into respective classes

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I&apos;m screen 1 (main.xml)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me to to go second screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I&apos;m screen 2 (main2.xml)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me to go to third screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main3.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I&apos;m screen 3 (main3.xml)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AppActivity**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


       button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, App2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

    }


}
```

**App2Activity**

```
public class App2Activity extends Activity {

        Button button;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);


           button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);   

                }

            });

        }


    }
```

**App3Activity**

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main3);



        }


    }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your_package_name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AppActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name=".App2Activity" >
        </activity>

          <activity

            android:name=".App3Activity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me an error on button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: A red line underneath the setOnClickListener

Comment: It says (Multiple markers at this line
 - OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the 
  arguments (new OnClickListener(){}))

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+O. Or just paste your class

Comment: Post the file where you are getting the redline

Comment: public class App3Activity extends Activity {
Button button2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


            button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(App3Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: I couldnt paste it in "Your Answer)

Comment: From App3, where you want to go? App1 or App2? This line `Intent intent = new Intent(App3Activity.this, App3Activity.class)` is wrong. Please check my answer. First parameter should be App2Activity

Comment: App go to main1 .. App2 go to main2 and App3 should go to main3

Comment: You're confused, seems like you're a naive to Android. Please go to developer.android.com and read first.